# Dynamically added input to form doesn't validate after first validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form where I add some inputs dinamically.

Every time the user select another "fornecedor" from addMaterialFornecedor select I add a input for preco.

My problem is that when I click the button and call the validate() function http://js.sapo.pt/SAPO/Ink/FormValidator/doc.html if I selected the "fornecedor"s before I click the button validate the form but if I click the button, selected the "fornecedor"s, and click again it will not validate :s

http://jsfiddle.net/rVQB4/3/

the javascript code I'm using:

```
function formValidate(form){

  if(!SAPO.Ink.FormValidator.validate(form, options)){
    //some debug
    console.log(form);
    return false;
  }else{
    //some ajax calls
    return false;
  }

}
```

Here is a video that exlain better the problem: https://dl.dropbox.com/u/6416035/stack3.ogv
sorry my english :s
thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Livequery works wonders for items dynamically added to a webpage by binding events to events dynamically added to the DOM. If this binding doesn't take place, events won't fire for those dynamic objects.

Here's an example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myDynamicObject").livequery(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
      // Do something.
    });
  });
});
```

See [here](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) for more information on how to use livequery.

Comment: I'll read it but just to add more information every time I click the button and look at the form in the console it have the new added input.

Comment: I don't understand how it can help me :s Because I don't have any event binding to that elements. :s

Comment: if you look at the video the input added worked, they just doesn't worked after click Adicionar :s